# Error al subir archivo a la carpeta del sitio web xampp desde localhost

Tags: php, sql, html5, xampp

el problema es que subo un archivo a xampp. pero me lo envia a la carpeta  xampp/tmp/   y no a la carpeta que requiero como /htdocs/sitioweb/archivos

pero el primer archivo que envio si lo sube correcta mente. los demas solo me hace el registro en la base de datos mas no me mueve el documento a la carpeta correcta.

> ejemplo : subo 1 archivo a la tabla archivos ( que esta vacia ) la
>   instruccion SQL se ejecuta correctamente. el archivo se mueve a
>   /htdocs/sitioweb/archivos todo OK. pero cuando subo el 2 ! hace el
>   registro en la tabla correcto. pero no lo direcciona a
>   /htdocs/sitioweb/archivos si no a /xampp/tmp/

Codigo :

```
require("connect_db.php");
$titulo =$_POST['titulo'];
$subidopor =$_POST['subidopor'];
$codigo =$_POST['codigo'];
$descripcion =$_POST['descripcion'];
$nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
$tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
$ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
$extension = pathinfo($nombre, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$extension = strtolower($extension);
$extension_correcta = ($extension == 'pdf' or $extension == 'docx' or $extension == 'xlsx');

if ($extension_correcta) {
        $ruta_destino_archivo = "../archivos/"; //locacion del documento actual ../menu/subirarchivo.php
        $archivo_ok = move_uploaded_file($nombre, $ruta_destino_archivo);  
        $guardar = $mysqli->query("insert into archivos (codigo,titulo,descripcion,tamanio,tipo,nombrearchivo,subidopor)VALUES('".$codigo."','".$titulo."','".$descripcion."','".$tamanio."','".$tipo."','".$nombre."','".$subidopor."')");
```

> nota: trabajo con PHP 7.2.3 y mariadb.  probe en linux y en windows .

Comment: Hola @Jay Puedes colocar el codigo aqui, por favor

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Este sitio está habilitado para que muestres las partes de código relevante. Es de poca ayuda que pongas un enlace a tu código. No lo he abierto, pero me temo que está allí **todo el archivo completo** cuando no el proyecto completo y... quien sabe, quizá tenga uno que descargárselo y analizar tu proyecto completo... Debes facilitar el trabajo a quienes quieran ayudarte, indicando los fragmentos de código donde está fallando y poniéndolo aquí, no en un enlace.

Comment: Supongo que el segundo archivo no se llama igual que el primero. En estos casos revisar el log de errores (en la carpeta donde se ejecuta el código de subida de archivos) sería lo mejor.

Comment: despues de escuchar 1 hora de electronica di con el error. $ruta_destino_archivo = "../archivos/'".$nombre."'";
        $archivo_ok = move_uploaded_file($ruta, $ruta_destino_archivo);

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba en la ruta.
antes:

```
$ruta_destino_archivo = "../archivos/"; 
$archivo_ok = move_uploaded_file($nombre, $ruta_destino_archivo);
```

Despues:

```
$ruta_destino_archivo = "../archivos/'".$nombre."'"; 
$archivo_ok = move_uploaded_file($ruta, $ruta_destino_archivo);

$ruta  proviene de $ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
```

Espero que les sirva a los que tenga el mismo problema.